# Problem with simultaneous key presses in Sony -Viao laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard

I got a new sony viao EB14 laptop last week. This laptop has a problem with the keyboard.
While playing games involving 3 or more simultaneous key presses, the keyboard fails to respond to more than 2 simultaneous key presses.
Please help.

Comment: Contact Sony Support!

Comment: Anyway, many keyboards have that problem. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Key_jamming_and_ghosting

Answer (score 1):

Many keyboards (including laptops), which are not designed for gaming, have
[key jamming and ghosting problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Key_jamming_and_ghosting).

One solution would be to buy a cheap USB keyboard, to play your games.

Comment: This is almost definitely the case, and you will probably not be able to do anything to fix the laptop keyboard.  [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)) explains it very thoroughly.  Most gaming keyboards have high enough key rollover so that this is not a problem.